# What is the recommended way for utilizing Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

i have the below broad cast receiver, and as sshown it contains lots of registered actions. my question is what is the reommended way for handling such broad cast receivers that contain lots of actions?
should i separate them in a separate file? or put them into a service?

please advice.

**update**:

in case i have to separate the receiver in a another file, how can i receive the updated notifications from it, and how can i based on the updated notification perform an action , ölike disabling a button"in the main activity" for an example?

**code**:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tvStatusLabel.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        //ACTION_FOUND
        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND"));

            BluetoothDevice stateExtDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            setBTDeviceExtrs(stateExtDevice);
            newDeviceFound = true;
            break;

        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED:
            int prevConnState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_CONNECTION_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            switch (prevConnState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevConnState: DISCONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevConnState:DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevConnState: CONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevConnState:CONNECTING");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevConnState: CONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevConnState:CONNECTED");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevConnState: DISCONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevConnState:DISCONNECTING");
                break;
            default:
                Log.wtf(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevConnState: UNHANDELED CASE"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevConnState: UNHANDELED CASE");
                break;
            }

            int currConnState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            switch (currConnState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currConnState: DISCONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currConnState: CONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:CONNECTING");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currConnState: CONNECTED"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:CONNECTED");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currConnState: DISCONNECTING"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:DISCONNECTING");
                break;
            default:
                Log.wtf(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currConnState: UNHANDELED CASE"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState: UNHANDELED CASE");
                break;
            }

            if (prevConnState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING && currConnState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "Profile connected"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:Profile connected");
            }
            if (prevConnState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTING && currConnState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "Profile disconnected"));
                tvStatus.setText("currConnState:Profile disconnected");
            }
            break;

        case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED:
            //ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED
            int prevBondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

            switch (prevBondState) {
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevBondState: BOND_BONDING"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevBondState:BOND_BONDING");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevBondState: BOND_BONDED"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevBondState:BOND_BONDED");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevBondState: BOND_NONE"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevBondState:BOND_NONE");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevBondState: NO_BONDING_STATE"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevBondState:NO_BONDING_STATE");
                break;
            }

            int currBondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
            switch (currBondState) {
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currBondState: BOND_BONDING"));
                tvStatus.setText("currBondState:BOND_BONDING");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currBondState: BOND_BONDED"));
                tvStatus.setText("currBondState:BOND_BONDED");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currBondState: BOND_NONE"));
                tvStatus.setText("currBondState:BOND_NONE");
                break;

            default:
                Log.wtf(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currBondState: NO_BONDING_STATE"));
                tvStatus.setText("currBondState:NO_BONDING_STATE");
                break;
            }

            if ( (prevBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) && (currBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if ( (prevBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) && (currBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unpaired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

            //ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
            //use AsyncTask to show busy indicator while discovering the adjacent devices.
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED"));
            tvStatus.setText("ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED");

            asyncDis = new AsyncDiscovery();
            asyncDis.execute();
            break;

            //ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED"));
            tvStatus.setText("ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");
            break;

            //ACTION_STATE_CHANGED
        case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED:
            Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED"));

            final int prevPowState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch (prevPowState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevPowState: STATE_ON"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevPowState: BT Turned ON.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevPowState: STATE_TURNING_ON"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevPowState: BT is Turning ON.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevPowState: STATE_TURNING_OFF"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevPowState: BT STATE_TURNING_OFF.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "prevPowState: STATE_OFF"));
                tvStatus.setText("prevPowState: BT STATE_OFF.");
                break;
            }

            final int currPowState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (currPowState) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currPowState: STATE_ON"));
                tvStatus.setText("currPowState: BT Turned ON.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currPowState: STATE_TURNING_ON"));
                tvStatus.setText("currPowState: BT is Turning ON.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currPowState: STATE_TURNING_OFF"));
                tvStatus.setText("currPowState: BT STATE_TURNING_OFF.");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                Log.d(TAG, LogAnd.show("onReceive", "currPowState: STATE_OFF"));
                tvStatus.setText("currPowState: BT STATE_OFF.");
                break;
            }

            if ( (prevPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON) && (currPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT-Power ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //initResources();
                if (!tbOnOff.isChecked()) {
                    tbOnOff.setChecked(true);
                }
                btnDiscover.setEnabled(true);
                btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(btnDiscoverListener);
            }
            if ( (prevPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF) && (currPowState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) ) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT-Power OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //resetResources();
                if (tbOnOff.isChecked()) {
                    tbOnOff.setChecked(false);
                }
                btnDiscover.setEnabled(false);
                btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(null);
                adapter.clear();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you put into Separate one file. Create Unique method for each one.

But if there is long task in particular action then it should be on services or thread.

Comment: thanks for ur answr. but can i make the broadcast receiver as service?i mean , can i crete a service and in it i use broadcast receiver becuse i want to receive notifications all the time? please advice

Comment: No, you can not make the broadcast receiver as service. You have to create two class 1 for broadcast Receiver and 1 for Service. You can do with service base on broadcast receive notification.